# Abrir conjunto de textos no python para aplicar funções (len,set,colocations,etc.). UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> import nltk    
>>> from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader  
>>> meucorpus='C:\Users\dudu\Desktop\Artigos sem acentos'   
>>> meustextos=PlaintextCorpusReader(meucorpus,'.*')  
>>> meustextos.words()  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>  
    meustextos.words()  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py", line 498, in wrapper  
    return method(self).encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py", line 664, in __repr__  
    for elt in self:  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 394,   in iterate_from  
    for tok in piece.iterate_from(max(0, start_tok-offset)):  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 291,   in iterate_from  
    tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\plaintext.py", line   117, in _read_word_block  
    words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1102, in readline  
    new_chars = self._read(readsize)  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1329, in _read  
    chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1359, in   _incr_decode  
    return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode  
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)  
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0:   invalid start byte
```

Comment: Primeiro - note que esse tipo de caminho `>>> meucorpus='C:\Users\dudu\Desktop\Artigos sem acentos' ` só  funcionou por acaso: a barra invertida ( \ ) é usada em Python, C e outras linguagens como caractere de escape, dando um significado especial a alguns caractéres que a seguem. Use a barra pra frente ( `/`) para separar pastas, ou duas barras (\\\)  (que são sempre interpretadas como uma única barra).

Answer (score 1):

Como a sua mensgaem de erro diz, você tem um arquivo que é um texto inválido em UTF-8: ou seja, apesar do seu nome de diretório ser "sem acentos", você tem texto acentuado lá sim. E a codificação de acentos não é a universal utf-8, ficando então uma boa probabilidade de ser `latin1` - que é a usada pelo Windows no Brasil, na interface gráfica.

A chamada à `PlaintextCorpusReader`suporta um argumento opcional com o encoding dos arquivos de texto - mude-a para:>>>

```
meustextos=PlaintextCorpusReader(meucorpus,'.*', encoding='latin1')
```

e o erro de UnicodeDecode error desaparecerá. No entanto, apesar de não ter nenhum erro visível, a não ser que todos os seus arquivos de texto estejam em Latin1, eles podem ser lidos incorretamente - se você tiver arquivos em  `utf-8` misturados no diretório, por exemplo, seus caractéres acentuados serão lidos como lixo - e você terá problemas com seus dados.

Se isso ocorrer, você terá que fazer uma normalização dos artigos de forma que todos fiquem numa única codificação de textos.